# Automating IE SaveAs Dialogue using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, automation

I am trying to create a scheduled automation in windows server using vbscript.

Following is the script i am using to automate the Save As dialogue. It is working fine when the server is connected to a display (using RDC) but failing when its scheduled to run headless. Am I missing something here.

```
Dim ReportPath
Dim oShell
ReportPath = WScript.Arguments(0)

if len(ReportPath) = 0 then
WScript.Quit
end if

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

oShell.AppActivate("Internet Explorer")

msgbox 

WScript.Sleep 2000
oShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

WScript.Sleep 2000  
oShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

WScript.Sleep 2000 
oShell.SendKeys "{Enter}"

WScript.Sleep 2000 
oShell.SendKeys ReportPath

WScript.Sleep 2000 
oShell.SendKeys "{Enter}"

' Return status of script execution
' WScript.StdOut.Write(returnVal)
```

Comment: There is nothing to `sendkeys` to. See `IDM_SAVEAS` Command ID - Saves the current Web page to a file - 
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770024(v=vs.85).aspx using `object.ExecWB(cmdID, cmdexecopt, pvaIn, pvaOut)` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752087(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Where are you opening/using the SaveAs dialog? Your code is doing something else